# Remove duplication of code in Laravel- optimize

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to how to optimize my code below without affecting its output in laravel?

```
 $user = User::with('voucherUtilizations.voucher')
                ->with('voucherUtilizations', function ($query) use($campaignId ,$date_from,$date_to) {
                    if ($campaignId && $date_from &&$date_to) {
                        return $query->where('campaign_id', $campaignId)
                                     ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date_from)
                                     ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date_to)
                                     ->whereNotNull('voucher_id');
                    }
                    if ($campaignId) {
                        return $query->where('campaign_id', $campaignId)
                                     ->whereNotNull('voucher_id',);
                    }
                    if ($date_from &&$date_to) {
                        return $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date_from)
                                     ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date_to)
                                     ->whereNotNull('voucher_id');
                    }
                })
                ->withCount(['voucherUtilizations as no_of_prizes_won' => function ($query) use($campaignId ,$date_from,$date_to){
                    //the same code above function
                }])
                ->where('id', $id->id)
                ->first()
```

some functions are repeated all common how can I minimize this code

Comment: without optimize this query working?

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya yes... can you suggest me any improvements?

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)
            ->with('voucherUtilizations.voucher')
            ->with(['voucherUtilizations', function ($query) use($campaignId, $date_from, $date_to) {
                    $query->when(!empty($campaignId), function ($q1) use ($campaignId) {
                                return $q1->where('campaign_id', $campaignId);
                            });
                    $query->when(!empty($date_from), function ($q2) use ($date_from) {
                                return $q2->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date_from);
                            });
                    $query->when(!empty($date_to), function ($q3) use ($date_to) {
                                return $q3->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date_to);
                            });
                }])
            ->withCount('voucherUtilizations')
            ->whereNotNull('voucher_id')
            ->first();
```

use [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) or also put if condition ,and value exist in if condition then return values,so not added 2 times same condition.

Hope fully it will help to you easily.

Comment: Happy to help you :)